# CSS transition fades out instantly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I know this is a common issue and i've read a lot about it and just cant implement the variety of solutions in my CSS code, please advice.

I have a simple `ul` and `li` elements, the fade in effect is working but the fade out dont. I know i need to put the transition code into the "normal" state of the `ul li` element, but it just wont work.

```
   #menu li a{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    #menu ul li{
        display: inline;
    }

    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:  0px;
        padding: 0px; 
    }

    #menu ul li a:hover {
        color: dodgerblue;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear 0s;
        -moz-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
        -ms-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
        -o-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
        transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
    }
```

Comment: Put the transition on the main element (` #menu li a`) not the hover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property (and vendor prefixes) within the `#menu li a` selector itself, as follows:

```css
#menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 15px;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
}

#menu ul li a:hover { color: dodgerblue; }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/69FZK/)**.

Answer (score 0):

use [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)   from lea verou add your code would then look like this :

```
#menu li a{
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family:arial;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        #menu ul li{
            display: inline;
        }

        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin:  0px;
            padding: 0px; 
        }

        #menu ul li a:hover {
            color: dodgerblue;
        }
        #menu ul li a {
            transition:color 0.3s linear 0s;
        }
```

you ca get a cdn version here [prefixfree](http://cdnjs.com/)